Use AWS AppSync to wrap existing GraphQL API and add GraphQL Subscriptions
I am building a macOS app that allow a user to interact with GitHub's GraphQL API.
However, they don't provide support for GraphQL's Subscriptions, which considering my use would be very powerful to use.
So my idea is to use AWS AppSync to wrap GitHub's GraphQL API (https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) and add Subscriptions myself. My AppSync GraphQL server will basically handle the subscriptions and then forward to GitHub's GraphQL API.
First of all I wanted to know if it was something that was possible to do. I'm pretty novice when it comes to AWS and GraphQL.
If possible, any advice or resources I should look up to?
Thanks for your help!
